# C# Regex - Loop through textbox?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove anything after // to the end.

Example:

```
Pickup0=1240,-2572.2773,651.0634,33.8931,-1 // text
Pickup1=1242,-2564.4270,651.1445,33.8931,-1 // text
Pickup2=358,-2559.6565,636.4931,14.4592,-1 // text42434
Pickup3=356,-2573.4871,636.5174,14.4592,-1 // blabla
```

I want it to be:

```
Pickup0=1240,-2572.2773,651.0634,33.8931,-1
Pickup1=1242,-2564.4270,651.1445,33.8931,-1
Pickup2=358,-2559.6565,636.4931,14.4592,-1
Pickup3=356,-2573.4871,636.5174,14.4592,-1
```

I could do it with this code, but it only removes the // one time and not all of them.

```
textBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"\//.*$", "");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to turn on the `m` (*multi-line*) [modifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#multiline) which causes `$` to match the end of each line.

```
Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"(?m)//.*$", "");
```

But the end of string `$` anchor is not necessary to use in this case because `.*` will match any character except newline, so you could just simply remove it from your regular expression.

```
Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"//.*", "");
```

Comment: Or replace `$` with `\n\r`

Comment: or `//.*` would be enough.

Comment: Regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, @"(?m)//.*$", "\n\r");  Managed it. thanks!